# why data getting insert after dispatched as invalid in google app engine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Iam trying to validate and insert a data. here if the username exists in file service it should dispatch with error message but after the validation it is dispatched with error message with inserting data in file service. I cant fine where am failing in code.

My JSP:

```
<form name="create" id="myform" action="/create" method="post">
User Name:  <input type="text" name="cliname"/>
<input type ="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

My Servlet:

```
public class CreateForm  extends HttpServlet {
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws IOException, ServletException {
       String uname = req.getParameter("cliname");
       Query query1 = new Query("Users");
List<Entity> cli_id = datastore.prepare(query1).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
for (Entity client : cli_id){
username = (String)client.getProperty("User Name");
if(username.equals(uname)) {
RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/Create.jsp");
req.setAttribute("errormsg", "User Name Already Exists");
rd.forward(req, resp);}}
Entity userInput = new Entity("Users");
userInput.setProperty("User Name", uname);
datastore.put(userInput);
}}
```

Kindly suggest me an idea,

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The property which you are setting and getting should not have spaces at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code.

```
public class CreateForm  extends HttpServlet {
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
   String uname = req.getParameter("cliname");
   Query query1 = new Query("Users");
   List<Entity> cli_id = datastore.prepare(query1).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
   RequestDispatcher rd = null;
for (Entity client : cli_id){
    username = (String)client.getProperty("User_Name");
    if(username.equals(uname)) {
        req.setAttribute("errormsg", "User Name Already Exists");
        rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
     }else{
        Entity userInput = new Entity("Users");
        userInput.setProperty("User_Name", uname);
        datastore.put(userInput);
        req.setAttribute("success", "User Name Added");
        rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/Create.jsp");
     }
 }
     rd.forward(req, resp);
   }
 }
```

Comment: i tried your updated code as it is ankur, data gets insert even it says already exists

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial from GAE Developers. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

Comment: it says about general way of using queries but by problem is it inserts data even after it says user exists.

Comment: Thank u ankur i got the answer finally just created a condition and solved the problem

Comment: Actually I also wanted you to solve it by your own. Try to debug your code while your are getting errors.